# What battery can I use for 1000kv brushless motor, that will be the cheapest?

Tags: esc, brushless-motors, lipo-batteries, power

I am using a 10 x 4.5 propeller for my A2212/13T 1000KV brushless motor with a 30A ESC. What battery will I need that will be cheap to power my motor alongside three 9-gram servos?
Flight time is not a big factor, I just need a cheap battery quickly.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any 3S Lipo would do your setup perfectly fine. Step up to a 4S Lipo if you’re interested in unlimited vertical. Get whatever mAh size that’ll fit your battery compartment. My recommendation for cheap is a 3S 3200mah. Around $30 for two on Amazon.

Comment: I bought a 2S Lipo battery, is that too little power?

Comment: @coolbean, 2s is likely to turn that propeller too slowly to generate enough thrust. Give it a try, it might be OK. If not, switching to a high-pitch propeller (like a 10x6 or 10x8) or even a larger propeller (like a 12x6) will make the motor draw more power.